# when unknown in combobox is selected show all null values

Tags: ms-access, combobox, null, filtering

I have a form that I can filter when the customer's name is selected in the combobox.(Combobox is called cmb_Customer.) Sometimes, the name of the customer is forgotten while entering the order information. For this, I want to add a person whose name is unknown, and I want null values to be shown only when this is selected.
Here is the code I wrote to filter my query according to the selected name.

```
like *&[Forms]![frmAll].[cmb_Customer]&* or is null
```

but of course, when you type it like this, the name of the searched customer + null values are displayed. However I want to show null values only when customer's name unknown is selected. how can i solve this?

Comment: Where is this criteria used - in dynamic parameterized query? If "unknown" is selected, do you want all records or just the ones where customer is Null?

Comment: I wrote this criteria in the query. I also created my form from this query. When unknown is selected, I want to show only where customers are null

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
WHERE Nz(Customer, "") = IIf(Forms!frmAll.cmb_Customer = "unknown", "", Forms!frmAll.cmb_Customer)
```

I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to build criteria and apply to form or report. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html